# moment.calendar shows today as the day instead of 5 days ago

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I am using moment version `2.24.0` (I did have an older version but updated to see if it fixed this problem, which it didn't), in Angular application.

I have the following code

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-duration-format';
....
    
public static formatTime(dateTime: Date): string {  
        // To test am subtracting 5 days from today..
        dateTime.setDate(dateTime.getDate() - 5);

        // dateTime now show Tuesday, which is correct
        let result = moment().calendar(dateTime);

        // Result show Sunday! (wrong)
        return result;
      }
```

I am subtracting 5 days just to test the `calendar()` formatting.

From the debugger:

[image]

As can be seen, the `calendar()` is displaying Sunday (which is today), but it should be Tuesday. Are there any workarounds for this?

### Update 1

Added a Plunker example of this [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7e6piCsNxKzVzBavTViF?p=preview).

See script.js for the code.

Comment: `let result = moment().calendar(dateTime.getDate());` this worked for me.

Comment: I am actually after the date and time, along with the descriptions given by `moment` (eg '5 days ago')

Comment: So, my answer did not help you?

Answer (score 0):

if you give 5 to setDate function:

```
dateTime.setDate(dateTime.getDate() - 5);
```

you get the correct time - 5 Milliseconds.

to get X days ago you need to give:

```
let today  = new Date()
5DaysAgo = new Date(today .getTime() - (5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Comment: I Googled how to subtract the days and `dateTime.setDate(dateTime.getDate() - 5);` was suggested. However, even with the above, moment still gives the wrong answer. See demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7e6piCsNxKzVzBavTViF?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using moment, why don't you just use it? In particular, instead of manipulating the `Date`, subtract 5 days using moment...

```js
console.log(moment(new Date()).subtract(5, 'days').calendar());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't actually want to subtract 5 days, this was just my test for the moment.calendar given any Date. See example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7e6piCsNxKzVzBavTViF?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
 let result = moment().calendar(dateTime.getDate());
```

Comment: It would be great if someone downvotes with a comment

Comment: May I know the reason please?